# Whats more obtrusive during a user interview, an audio recorder or a colleague taking notes.

Tags: user-research, users, user-interviews

From experience, which has caused more of a barrier to a candiadate feeling relaxed or giving an acurate detailed answer?

Comment: Your question is a bit short and shows lack of your own research. Can you give a little more context?

Comment: You should ideally have both in all situations.

Comment: I have re-read this question several times, and I am still not sure what you're asking. I feel like using the word 'candidate' refers to someone you're interviewing for a job, not someone you're interviewing about their experience. Given that the topic and the content of your question are both relatively incomplete, this is a hard question to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one.

**Audio Recording:** Audio recording is good and discrete, but you are recording only audio. In terms of data, you will have a lack of information in terms of facial and body expressions (reactions).

**Video Recording:** You will collect audio and video, so you'll cover answers and facial and body expressions (reactions).

**Screen Recording:** If we are talking about digital products, **this is the must**. Try to combine heatmaps as well with your product if it's possible.

**Taking notes:** Someone taking notes could hurt your interview process because the user can start paying attention to your colleagues who are taking notes. This can cause feeling that the user is doing something wrong every time when your colleagues write something.

**Advice:**

> My suggestion is to combine Video Recording + Screen Recording and if
>   it's necessary to take a few notes, but not more than that.
>
> When you are doing user interviews user is already prepared to be
>   "brain-raped", so video and screen recording should not affect to
>   results.
>
> I had a few situations where users started very carefully with the
>   answers because they had felt being recorded, after a few minutes that
>   feeling disappeared.
>
> Give users clear explanation that they can't do anything wrong during
>   the interview, and all "errors" are addressed to UX department.

Comment: "_I had a few situations where users started very carefully with the answers_" Could starting with two or three "throwaway" questions help with this? You'd want them to not sound "made up", but could be about some aspect you're not really interested in. By the time you get to the "real" questions, the user will hopefully have acclimatised.

Comment: You need to have the experience to handle user interviews.
To feel how the user feels, and to adjust the direction of the interview based on their feelings. 
Also, the personality of the person is very important on both sides of the table .